# Angular 2 frontend django 2 REST framework backend user auth

Tags: javascript, django, angular, django-rest-framework

I'm new to Django and JavaScript, so please forgive me if this is an obvious question.

What is the best way to authenticate users?

I can only find posts about using [this](https://github.com/GetBlimp/django-rest-framework-jwt) which doesn't support django 2.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`django-rest-framework` provides several solutions for authentication. I recommend to read carefully the docs : http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/

I've already used **Token authentication** on several projects and it works fine:

You need to install the `rest_framework.authtoken` app in your project. This app is provided with django-rest-framework

Then you need create a token for every user. There are several ways described in the docs.

On the client side, you need to implement a login form. Your backend will check user and password and gets back the user token.

Then you can pass this token in the header of every request:

```
Authorization: Token value-of-the-token
```

Make sure to use `https` if you use Token authentication.